How can I change this shower valve stem?

I need help replacing this valve stem, it's old and the grooves have worn where it won't hold a handle anymore. Unfortunately I don't know the brand and can't find the branding anywhere on the handles.
Can anyone assist in what brand this might be and the process to replace this ? I can't find any branding on it.
There appears to be a nut to turn at the base of it, but I don't know if it's as simple as turning the water off, unscrewing that and finding the appropriate replacement.
Appreciate any help.

Take the valve stem and pictures to a smaller local hardware store that carries the older stuff.

unscrew the nut on the wall

If the issue is only the handles will not fit tight, try this Universal handle Kit .
The kit is designed so you can replace handles on stems that are worn. I have used this kit on an old shower set that had the same problem of stripped splines .

Do you own this property?  If you are renting, this answer is not for you.
It is very likely that by turning the water off and removing the noted nut you'll be able to remove the cartridge, which is the inner half of the valve.   Take that to a plumbing specialist supplier to see if a replacement can be found.
Hopefully then you can use the new cartridge or if you cannot find one, put back the old one and use the handle kit suggested in another answer.
It is possible, also, that while removing the cartridge you will break it, or the valve, or you'll find the valve body is hopelessly damaged, or for some other reason ... you will not be able to reassemble it.  You need to be prepared for this, and willing to deal with it as follows:

If the bathroom has its own shutoff valve, you will have to live without the bathroom for a while.   Make a plan to replace the valve and probably all the plumbing serving this shower, and to refinish the wall.
If the bathroom does not have its own shutoff valve, you will have to do all the above but also to immediately break open this wall, cut the pipes to the shower valve, and cap them so that you can turn the home's water back on while planning next steps.

It's unlikely that you won't be able to at least return the shower to its original state as pictured in your question, but you need to be aware of and willing to take the plunge if things go wrong while taking it part.

It is very assumptive to think the OP is renting. There is no mention of renting or any claim that there was anything reported to a landlord. Using your logic, a disclaimer should be added to every post.  Also there was no mention of dripping water or valves that will not shut the water off.  However old fixtures having worn splines is fairly common and the reason for the replacement kit.

I am the owner. It's simply an old worn fixture
